# Postfix issue on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I have a little issue with my Postfix, I can't receive any email... 
Every time I try to send an email from an external source, I receive :

```
Jul 28 11:05:38 DESTHOSTNAME postfix/smtpd[24871]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from SENDERHOSTNAME[SENDERIP]: 454 4.7.1 <DESTEMAIL>: Relay access denied; from=<SENDEREMAIL> to=<DESTEMAIL> proto=ESMTP helo=<SENDERHOSTNAME>
```

Here is my output of postconf -n :

```
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: logical line must not start with whitespace: "    mynetworks_style = host   ..."
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_protocols = ipv4, ipv6
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 pband.ch
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname, check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo_access
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks , permit_sasl_authenticated , defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
```

I found a lot of post about the same issue but impossible to fix this issue...

Any idea to help me ?

Thank you,
MrDaves

Comment: Please [accept the answer that helped you](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers), or post an answer yourself, rather than changing the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`logical line must not start with whitespace` indicates that there are some extra whitespace in the config file.

Check your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` for lines starting with whitespace. It could be a space in the beginning of the line or maybe line break in the wrong place.

Comment: Yey  the error changed now :)

Jul 29 11:25:48 HOSTNAME postfix/smtpd[1807]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from SENDERSERVER[SENDERIP]: 451 4.3.0 <DESTMAIL>: Temporary lookup                                                                 failure; from=<SENDERMAIL> to=<DESTMAIL> proto=ESMTP helo=<SENDSERVER>

I will restart my google search with this error...

But a little question : I used the default config and I had error like these ? :(

Comment: [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/506347/postfix-temporary-lookup-failure) This link helped me with this error ! everything is OK
Thank you :)